# html dynamic data pulling from database

Tags: html

am using this code to fetch the data from the database to html page

i have to send html newsletters to clients so instead of creating more html templates 
i want to create one and i have to fetch the data dynamically from database for each client

can any body help on this

but this is not working can anybody help me on this

```
<?php

 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root"); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_select = mysql_select_db("STrack",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
?>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Step 5</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="cssstyle">
 <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where Name='Admin', $db);
 if (!$result)
      {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
     {
echo $result;
 }
?>
</div>
 </body>
</html>

<?php

 mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: do we have to enable php for this to happen 
can anybody say ...for my above post ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand corectly, because I dont really get your question, but here is what I reccomend using: [AJAX - Click me](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp). Its not that hard, and gets your data dynamically:)

Comment: do we have to enable php for this to happen 
can anybody say ...for my above post ...

Comment: I do not understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish...Can you share some more details?

Comment: What do you mean by enabling php?

Comment: try reading http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ this, and some more about php looping here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp . Ajax gets your database date dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Just regarding the errors in your code, maybe not the answer to your question

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where Name='Admin', $db);
```

missing a quote, it should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where Name='Admin'", $db);
```

In this code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
    echo $result;
}
```

You should use

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    echo $row[0]; // or echo $row['Name'];
}
```

Comment: can u help me further i have made the changes but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't try outputing the $result variable, that is only for reading via mysql functions

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Also not, with the "SELECT *" you are selecting every Database column. I assume you just want one or two columns.

for the output use

```
echo $row['<columnName>'];
```

Comment: can u help me further